# Has there ever been a successful, philosophically defensible refutation of the Epicurean Paradox?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-religion, paradox

"God said it, I believe it, and that settles it", is the final refuge of faith-based rhetoric, not a viable philosophical position. Has any significant religious thinker of any stripe constructed a refutation of the paradox of evil attributed to Epicurus: 'If god is willing to prevent evil, but unable, then he is not omnipotent; If he is able but unwilling, then he is malevolent; If he is both able and willing, then whence cometh evil; If he is neither able nor willing, then why call him god?'

Comment: Yes, the standard response is that the inference in the second horn ("if he is able but unwilling, then he is malevolent") is invalid. There is a reason for God to tolerate evil other than malevolence - preserving free will. Subverting free will to prevent evil would be a greater evil. The issue is generally discussed under the name of theodicy, see [SEP, The Problem of Evil](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/evil/).

Comment: In addition to the free will argument against the second horn, there is also the "defense from plenitude" at https://www.jstor.org/stable/40012554 and also available from the paywall-bypassing site sci-hub.st at https://sci-hub.st/10.1007/BF00135826 ...see in particular the discussion starting on p. 31 of various arguments that a world with a mix of "significantly free creatures (sfc's)" of varying degrees of virtue is in some sense "better" than a world where everyone is perfectly virtuous, even if that virtue is compatible with free will.

Comment: The question of why a 'good' God allows evil exists only in dualistic religions/philosophies which assert an extra-cosmic Godhead. The question does not arise in monistic traditions as it is incongruous with monistic logic. Read Plotinus' Six Enneads.

Comment: @Conifold; why would an *omnipotent* god have any problems allowing free will without evil.
After all; he did so in heaven, right?

Comment: Because preventing evil with free will around is nonsense like round squares, if it is free there are no constraints to do the preventing. Omnipotence or lack thereof is irrelevant. Those in heaven freely choose to follow God's will, but it is their choice, not God's doing. Those here can choose that too, but don't.

Comment: "Preserving free will" is not defensible. Free will itself is not an irrefutable given, and its 'preservation' as a function of any viable deity is not justifiable. Since both 'good' and 'evil' are culturally defined and often contradictory, the deity creating them would, in fact, be situational and at odds with itself. So why call him god?

Comment: If 'good' and 'evil' are only culturally defined and contradictory then there is no problem of evil in the first place, and no Epicurean argument to respond to. It does not even get to free will.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda You are right, of course, that the argument only works against certain conceptions of God. So it is odd that it is attributed to Epicurus who lived 341–270 B.C.E; the attribution is by one Lactantius c. 250 – c. 325 CE. Christianity was very much around at that time, but vigorously contested. It is hard to understand what Epicurus would have been attacking in this argument, when he wouldn't have had the relevant conception of God or even of atheism, so I'm not convinced it was his - not in this form anyway. Which doesn't make it any easier to "solve".

Comment: Why does illumination, like gravity, follow *the inverse square law*? 

Answer (score 3):

I think that **Leibniz's theodicy** is an attempt to settle this paradox. He basically argues that there are three sorts of evil in the world :

- Metaphysical evil, which is necessary since only God himself can be perfect, therefore the world is not.
- Physical and moral evil, which are allowed to exist because they enable a greater good if one is able to look at the broader picture.

Hence "Everything is for the better in the best *possible* world", i.e God reduced evil to the minimal amount.

Comment: And which category does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onchocerciasis (eye eating worms) causing blindness in children fall under?

Comment: 1) But we are created in gods' image, therefore we are also perfect.
2) Why is this needed; if god is omnipotent, surely he can enable the greater good without any evil
3) For the christian god, the "minimal amount of evil" is zero, else he isn't omnipotent

Comment: Define 'minimal amount'. Is the death of 2 million children (give or take) world-wide per year to violence and deprivation a minimum amount? Both physical and moral evil are culturally defined, so which culture's god enabled the most 'greater good' by virtue of the types of physical and moral evil allowed?

Comment: The argument is about the least amount of evil logically **possible**. 
The flaws you point out are not new, they are actually one of the central ideas in Voltaire's Candide, in which the eponymous main character gradually comes to reject this view (which is the one of his master Pangloss) as he is confronted with the evils of the world (slavery, executions, etc).

Comment: Of course, the idea of omnipotence entails several apparent paradoxes, and I personally reject the naive conception of an omnipotent God but Leibniz's argument is **consistent**, and I think that this is the main point

Comment: @ThisIsMe 1) We're created in god's image, and god could make us perfect but he didn't,  god wanted the image to be imperfect via a finite defected body covering the created soul, thus the soul is perfect but the whole image is not. 2) If god created a world with zero amount of evil, I can imagine it's not challenging enough for the soul to embody, shine, and unfold itself and the whole world may be very dull without any motivation/desire to improve oneself, and thus may be actually less perfect than this "best" world.

Comment: @ Double Knot I must have misunderstood you. You seem to be implying that heaven would (will?) be very dull. I have heard that suggested, but only as a joke.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is, No.

If you believe that God exists and is omnipotent, omniscient and benevolent, Leibniz' theory is probably the best that can be done.

From the perspective of someone who is agnostic, atheist or has a different conception of God, the argument turns on the balance between competing values. Voltaire's *Candide* is the classic response to Leibniz.

You may argue that his outrage at the suffering of innocents is not philosophically relevant. That may be so, but it is certainly morally relevant and constitutes an argument that the moral balance implied by Leibniz' argument should be unacceptable.

The conclusion is only that the conception of God as omnipotent, omniscient and benevolent is not correct. What follows from that needs further argument. Atheism does not necessarily follow - a different conception of God, or some form of agnosticism (including the view that we are not equipped to understand these matters) could be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think frankly it’s quite idiotic to try to view the actions of God or a God’s behaviours through a human lense. We only have a small part of the big picture and it’s inaccurate to try and judge God’s actions by what we know and concepts we came up with.